# How the inner 'for loop' 's iterator is getting incremented?

Tags: c#, for-loop, break

I have a function that generates prime numbers.

The inner 'for-loop' has got two condition checking statements, that ultimately result breaking of inner 'for-loop'.. 
So, after the inner for-loop breaks, control shifts to the outer for-loop, and again the inner for-loop is encountered, and the inner for-loop starts its execution with the incremented value of `k`.

When was the value incremented, instead it breaks it execution for the specified conditions of `if`?
Will anybody explain me the working of this code inside the function ?

```
public void prime()

    {
        int i = 5;

        for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 2; k <= i; k++)
            {
                if (j == k)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(j);

                    break;
                }
                else if (j % k == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Output:

```
2
3
5
```

Comment: You should step through in the debugger to see what this code does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a brute force method, it tests all numbers from `2 .. limit` against all previous numbers (again, from `2 .. current`) searching for multiples, if a multiple is found then the number is not a prime number.

I added some comments to the code to make it easier to understand:

```
public void prime () {
    int limit = 5;

    /**
     * Starting at 2, assuming the first prime number is 2
     * Test all numbers against any number from 2, if the
     * number being tested is a multiple of some other
     * previous number, that number is NOT a prime
     */
    for (int being_tested = 2; being_tested <= limit; being_tested++) {
        for (int previous_value = 2; previous_value <= limit; previous_value++) {
            /**
             * If previous_value == being_tested then
             * no multiples have been found
             * thus "being_tested" is a prime number
             */
            if (being_tested == previous_value) {
                Console.WriteLine(being_tested);
                break;
            }
            /**
             * If modulus == 0 then "being_tested"
             * is a multiple of previous_value,
             * therefore, not a prime number
             */
            else if (being_tested % previous_value == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: the original code I posted had the conditionals inverted and wouldn't run as expected, thanks to [@Cemafor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369685/how-the-inner-for-loop-s-iterator-is-getting-incremented#comment25210783_17369975) for pointing it out.

Comment: The two if statements need to be switched back, otherwise if `outer == inner` then the `outer % inner == 0` would trip and it would not output.

Comment: Here are two ways to improve your algorithm. First, you only need to check if being_tested is divisible by numbers less than or equal to its square root. Everything after that is overkill since you've implicitly checked it already. Second, all primes greater than 5 are either 1 greater or 1 less than a multiple of 6.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, here is a detailed walkthrough...`k` starts at 2 every time because `k` is declared inside the for loop. First run...`j = 2 k =2` so the first if condition is met. The break returns it to the outer for loop and increments `j` to 3. `j = 3 k = 2`...neither if is met. k increments...`j = 3 k =3` meets the condition of the first if and breaks. `j` increments...`j = 4 k =2`. First pass through causes the second if expression to return true because `4 % 2 == 0`. Breaks the inner for loop and returns to the outer loop. `j` increments to 5. Runs the inner loop until `k` is incremented to 5 and the first if condition validates to true. The second if condition only validates to true if `j` is even and will do so on the first iteration of the loop

Comment: This will generate primes up to `i` by incrementing `j` and checking to see if any numbers less then `j` are factors.

Answer (score 0):

When the break is encounted, it breaks out of the inner loop and continues after the loop. The inner loop is the only thing in the outer loop, so the next iteration of the outer loop is executed. This increments `j`.  When the inner loop is executed again, `k` is set back to `2` and the loop is started again.  The previous value of `k` (from the previous iteration of the outer loop) is lost.

The function itself is generating primes by `j` counting up and then checking every number less then it (values of `k`) to see if `j % k == 0` (not prime, k is a factor of j) or `j == k` (no factors found so far so j must be prime).

The inner loop itself technicly loops to `i`, but when `k` reaches `j` the loop is broken out of so `k` will only reach `i` when `j` also equals `i`.